# Penalizing small values

Tags: scoring-algorithm

I have the recency of each people of a given website computed as the number of days since last connexion.

`0` for people who connected the same day of the analysis
...
`25` for people who connected `25` days ago and are inactive since then.

Now I want to add recency with other factors such as frequency, etc... to compute a global activity score. But I also want to penalize inactivity before adding the recency score to the others.

People with a recency of `0` are strongly active, people with recency of `25` are inactive and a penalty should be applied to them.

So:

- I want to transform recency number into a score. The largest value should be the most recent, the smallest value should be the least recent.
- I want to penalize the smallest scores

I thought of something like:

- 1/(1+recency) for converting recency days into scores
- and applying a log function to penalize small numbers

I'm not sure what is the best way to get what I want and what makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide what you want-there is a function to do that.  If $r$ is recency, the simplest is to subtract $r$ from the score.  If that is too big a penalty, subtract $ar$ for some constant $a$.  Is $r=3$ lots worse than $r=1?$  How about $r=25$ compared to $r=5$?  As you say, you can just add $\frac 1{a+r}$ to all your scores.  As $a$ grows, the variation decreases.   You can also subtract $\log r$.  These are all monotonically decreasing with $r$.  Since you haven't said what you want beyond that, I can't suggest one over the other.